# Redirect stdtout in Python 2.x

Tags: python, string, redirect, stdout

I need to redirect several outputs from `stdout`
For example:

```
def main(dict):
    result = []
    real_stdout = sys.stdout
    fake_stdout = io.BytesIO()
    sys.stdout = fake_stdout
    print ("""long
string""")
    sys.stdout = real_stdout
    output_string = fake_stdout.getvalue()
    result["1"] = output_string[:-1]

    #fake_stdout.flush()
    real_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = fake_stdout
    print ("""new long string""")
    sys.stdout = real_stdout
    output_string = fake_stdout.getvalue()
    fake_stdout.close()

    sys.stdout = real_stdout

    fake_stdout.close()
    result["2"] = output_string[:-1]
    return result
```

I expect that the output will be

```
[{"1", 'long\n string'}, {"2", 'new long string'}]
```

But I get

```
[{"1", 'long\n string'}, {"2", 'long\n stringnew long string'}]
```

How do I clean a `fake_stdout` before second redirection?

Is it a good way to make redirection and `io.BytesIO()` can be used to save any length string redirected from `stdout`?

I can't use `capture_output from IPython.utils.io import`

Answer (score 0):

I usually use StringIO for similar usage, and being a file-like object it has the `truncate` method, maybe BytesIO has it too. Try `fake_stout.truncate(0)`